# Script on creating users work on localhost but not on the server

Tags: php, mysql, google-cloud-platform, localhost

The code works well in xamp on my localhost but when I upload it to the cloud server, it is unsuccessful and does not give any error. I checked if the issue was in creating arrays but since there are other scripts in the website creating arrays in a similar manner, I ruled it out. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
 <?php

 require_once 'core/core.php';  



//Get Site Settings Data
$query = DB::getInstance()->get("settings", "*", ["id" => 1]);
if ($query->count()) {
 foreach($query->results() as $row) {
    $title = $row->title;
    $use_icon = $row->use_icon;
    $site_icon = $row->site_icon;
    $tagline = $row->tagline;
    $description = $row->description;
    $keywords = $row->keywords;
    $author = $row->author;
    $bgimage = $row->bgimage;
 }          
}

  //Get Payments Settings Data
 $q1 = DB::getInstance()->get("payments_settings", "*", ["id" => 1]);
 if ($q1->count()) {
  foreach($q1->results() as $r1) {
$currency = $r1->currency;
$membershipid = $r1->membershipid;
 }          
}
 //Getting Payement Id from Database
 $query = DB::getInstance()->get("membership_freelancer", "*", ["membershipid" => $membershipid]);
if ($query->count() === 1) {
  $q1 = DB::getInstance()->get("membership_freelancer", "*", ["membershipid" => $membershipid]);
} else {
  $q1 = DB::getInstance()->get("membership_agency", "*", ["membershipid" => $membershipid]);
}
if ($q1->count() === 1) {
 foreach($q1->results() as $r1) {
   $bids = $r1->bids;
 }
}

 //Register Function
 if (Input::exists()) {
 if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))){

$errorHandler = new ErrorHandler;

$validator = new Validator($errorHandler);

$validation = $validator->check($_POST, [
  'name' => [
     'required' => true,
     'minlength' => 2,
     'maxlength' => 50
   ],
  'email' => [
     'required' => true,
     'email' => true,
     'maxlength' => 100,
     'minlength' => 2,
     'unique' => 'freelancer',
     'unique' => 'client'
  ],             
  'username' => [
     'required' => true,
     'maxlength' => 20,
     'minlength' => 3,
     'unique' => 'freelancer',
     'unique' => 'client'
  ],
   'password' => [
     'required' => true,
     'minlength' => 6
   ],
   'confirmPassword' => [
     'match' => 'password'
   ]
]);

  if (!$validation->fails()) {

      if (Input::get('user_type') === 'on') {

            $client = new Client();

            $remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false;
            $salt = Hash::salt(32);  
            $imagelocation = 'uploads/default.png';
            $clientid = uniqueid(); 
            try{

              $client->create(array(
               'clientid' => $clientid,
               'username' => Input::get('username'),
               'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
               'salt' => $salt,
               'name' => Input::get('name'),
               'email' => Input::get('email'),
               'imagelocation' => $imagelocation,
               'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
               'active' => 1,
               'user_type' => 1
              ));   

            if ($client) {
             $login = $client->login(Input::get('email'), Input::get('password'), $remember);
             Redirect::to('Client/');
            }else {
             $hasError = true;
           }

            }catch(Exception $e){
             die($e->getMessage()); 
            }                       

      } else {
        if($membershipid != ''){
            $freelancer = new Freelancer();

            $remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false;
            $salt = Hash::salt(32);  
            $imagelocation = 'uploads/default.png';
            $bgimage = 'uploads/bg/default.jpg';
            $freelancerid = uniqueid(); 
            try{

              $freelancer->create(array(
               'freelancerid' => $freelancerid,
               'username' => Input::get('username'),
               'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
               'salt' => $salt,
               'name' => Input::get('name'),
               'email' => Input::get('email'),
               'imagelocation' => $imagelocation,
               'bgimage' => $bgimage,
               'membershipid' => $membershipid,
               'membership_bids' => $bids,
               'membership_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
               'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
               'active' => 1,
               'user_type' => 1
              ));   

            if ($freelancer) {
             $login = $freelancer->login(Input::get('email'),                      Input::get('password'), $remember);
             Redirect::to('Freelancer/');
            }else {
             $hasError = true;
           }

            }catch(Exception $e){
             die($e->getMessage()); 
            }   
          } else {
              $memError = true;
            }
      }


  } else {
     $error = '';
     foreach ($validation->errors()->all() as $err) {
        $str = implode(" ",$err);
        $error .= '
               <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                <strong>Error!</strong> '.$str.'<br/>
               </div>
               ';
     }

  }

}     

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="en" class="no-js"> 
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>

    <!-- ==============================================
    Title and Meta Tags
    =============================================== -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php echo escape($title) .' - '. escape($tagline) ; ?></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo escape($description); ?>">
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo escape($keywords); ?>">
    <meta name="author" content="<?php echo escape($author); ?>">

    <!-- ==============================================
    Favicons
    =============================================== --> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicons/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/favicons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/favicons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

    <!-- ==============================================
    CSS
    =============================================== -->
    <!-- Style-->
    <link href="assets/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- ==============================================
    Feauture Detection
    =============================================== -->
    <script src="assets/js/modernizr-custom.js"></script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">         </script>
    <![endif]-->        

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Paste this code after body tag -->
    <div class="loader">
    <div class="se-pre-con"></div>
</div>


 <? 
 $basename = basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], ".php");
 $editname = basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
 $test = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
  ?>
 <!-- ==============================================
 Navigation Section
 =============================================== -->
<header id="header" headroom="" role="banner" tolerance="5" offset="700" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar--white ng-isolate-scope headroom headroom--top">
  <nav role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle header-nav__button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main">
        <span class="icon-bar header-nav__button-line"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar header-nav__button-line"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar header-nav__button-line"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="header-nav__logo">
        <a class="header-nav__logo-link navbar-brand" href="index.php">
        <?php if($use_icon === '1'): ?>
            <i class="fa <?php echo $site_icon; ?>"></i>
        <?php endif; ?>  <?php echo escape($title); ?></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-main navbar-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav header-nav__navigation">
        <li class="header-nav__navigation-item
         <?php echo $active = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] && $test === '') ? ' active' : ''; echo $active = ($basename == 'index') ? ' active' : ''; ?>">
          <a href="index.php" class="header-nav__navigation-link">
            <?php echo $lang['home']; ?>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="header-nav__navigation-item <?php echo $active = ($basename == 'jobs') ? ' active' : ''; echo $active = ($editname == 'jobpost.php?title='. Input::get('title').'') ? ' active' : '';?>">
          <a href="jobs.php" class="header-nav__navigation-link ">
            <?php echo $lang['jobs']; ?>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="header-nav__navigation-item <?php echo $active = ($basename == 'services') ? ' active' : ''; echo $active = ($editname == 'freelancer.php?a='. Input::get('a').'&id='. Input::get('id').'') ? ' active' : ''; ?>">
          <a href="services.php" class="header-nav__navigation-link ">
            <?php echo $lang['services']; ?>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="header-nav__navigation-item <?php echo $active = ($basename == 'about') ? ' active' : ''; ?>">
          <a href="about.php" class="header-nav__navigation-link ">
            <?php echo $lang['about']; ?>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="header-nav__navigation-item <?php echo $active = ($basename == 'how') ? ' active' : ''; ?>">
          <a href="how.php" class="header-nav__navigation-link ">
            <?php echo $lang['how']; ?> <?php echo $lang['it']; ?> <?php echo $lang['works']; ?>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="header-nav__navigation-item <?php echo $active = ($basename == 'faq') ? ' active' : ''; ?>">
          <a href="faq.php" class="header-nav__navigation-link ">
            <?php echo $lang['faq']; ?>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="header-nav__navigation-item <?php echo $active = ($basename == 'contact') ? ' active' : ''; ?>">
          <a href="contact.php" class="header-nav__navigation-link ">
            <?php echo $lang['contact']; ?>
          </a>
        </li>

     <?php
     //Start new Admin object
     $admin = new Admin();
     //Start new Client object
     $client = new Client();
     //Start new Freelancer object
     $freelancer = new Freelancer(); 

     if ($admin->isLoggedIn()) { ?>
          <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
            <!-- Menu Toggle Button -->
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <!-- The user image in the navbar-->
            <?php // echo $profileimg; ?>
              <img src="Admin/<?php echo escape($admin->data()->imagelocation); ?>" class="user-image" alt="User Image"/>

              <!-- hidden-xs hides the username on small devices so only the image appears. -->
              <span class="hidden-xs">
                <?php echo escape($admin->data()->name); ?>
              </span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="m_2"><a href="Admin/dashboard.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><?php echo $lang['dashboard']; ?></a></li>
                    <li class="m_2"><a href="Admin/profile.php?a=profile"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><?php echo $lang['view']; ?> <?php echo $lang['profile']; ?></a></li>
                    <li class="m_2"><a href="Admin/logout.php"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> <?php echo $lang['logout']; ?></a></li>   
            </ul>
          </li>
    <?php } elseif($client->isLoggedIn()) { ?>
          <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
            <!-- Menu Toggle Button -->
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <!-- The user image in the navbar-->
            <?php // echo $profileimg; ?>
              <img src="Client/<?php echo escape($client->data()->imagelocation); ?>" class="user-image" alt="User Image"/>

              <!-- hidden-xs hides the username on small devices so only the image appears. -->
              <span class="hidden-xs">
                <?php echo escape($client->data()->name); ?>
              </span>
            </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="m_2"><a href="Client/dashboard.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><?php echo $lang['dashboard']; ?></a></li>
                    <li class="m_2"><a href="Client/profile.php?a=profile"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><?php echo $lang['view']; ?> <?php echo $lang['profile']; ?></a></li>
                    <li class="m_2"><a href="Client/logout.php"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> <?php echo $lang['logout']; ?></a></li>  
            </ul>
          </li>
        <?php } elseif($freelancer->isLoggedIn()) { ?>
          <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
            <!-- Menu Toggle Button -->
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <!-- The user image in the navbar-->
            <?php // echo $profileimg; ?>
              <img src="Freelancer/<?php echo escape($freelancer->data()->imagelocation); ?>" class="user-image" alt="User Image"/>

              <!-- hidden-xs hides the username on small devices so only the image appears. -->
              <span class="hidden-xs">
                <?php echo escape($freelancer->data()->name); ?>
              </span>
            </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="m_2"><a href="Freelancer/index.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><?php echo $lang['dashboard']; ?></a></li>
                    <li class="m_2"><a href="Freelancer/profile.php?a=profile"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><?php echo $lang['view']; ?> <?php echo $lang['profile']; ?></a></li>
                    <li class="m_2"><a href="Freelancer/logout.php"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> <?php echo $lang['logout']; ?></a></li>  
            </ul>
          </li>
        <?php } else { ?>                       
            <li class="header-nav__navigation-item <?php echo $active = ($basename == 'login') ? ' active' : ''; echo $active = ($basename == 'forgot') ? ' active' : ''; echo $active = ($basename == 'reset') ? ' active' : ''; ?>">
          <a class="header-nav__navigation-link" href="login.php"><?php echo $lang['login']; ?></a>
        </li>
            <li class="header-nav__navigation-item <?php echo $active = ($basename == 'register') ? ' active' : ''; ?>">
            <a class="header-nav__navigation-link header-nav__navigation-link--outline" href="register.php"><?php echo $lang['signup']; ?> <?php echo $lang['for']; ?> <?php echo $lang['free']; ?></a>
                 </li>
             <?php }     ?>                         

          <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
            <!-- Menu Toggle Button -->
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <?php echo $lang['languages']; ?>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="m_2"><a href="<?php echo $test; ?>?lang=english">English</a></li>
                <li class="m_2"><a href="<?php echo $test; ?>?lang=french">French</a></li>
                <li class="m_2"><a href="<?php echo $test; ?>?lang=german">German</a></li>  
                <li class="m_2"><a href="<?php echo $test; ?>?lang=portuguese">Portuguese</a></li>
                <li class="m_2"><a href="<?php echo $test; ?>?lang=spanish">Spanish</a></li>
                <li class="m_2"><a href="<?php echo $test; ?>?lang=russian">Russian</a></li>    
                <li class="m_2"><a href="<?php echo $test; ?>?lang=chinese">Chinese</a></li>    
            </ul>
          </li>



      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>      

 <!-- ==============================================
 Header
 =============================================== -->     
 <header class="header-login" style="
background: linear-gradient(
  rgba(34,34,34,0.7), 
  rgba(34,34,34,0.7)
), url('<?php echo $bgimage; ?>') no-repeat center center fixed;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center center;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   color: #fff;
   height: 55vh;
   width: 100%;

   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   text-align: center; ">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
     <h1 class="revealOnScroll" data-animation="fadeInDown">
        <?php if($use_icon === '1'): ?>
            <i class="fa <?php echo $site_icon; ?>"></i>
        <?php endif; ?>  <?php echo escape($title); ?></h1>
     <div id="typed-strings">
      <span><?php echo escape($tagline); ?></span>
     </div>
     <p id="typed"></p>
    </div><!-- /.row -->
   </div><!-- /.content -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
 </header><!-- /header -->

 <!-- ==============================================
 Banner Login Section
 =============================================== -->
 <section class="banner-login">
  <div class="container">

   <div class="row">

    <main class="main main-signup col-lg-12">
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 text-center">

    <?php if(isset($memError)) { //If errors are found ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
     <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
     <strong><?php echo $lang['hasError']; ?></strong> <?php echo $lang['mem_error']; ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if(isset($hasError)) { //If errors are found ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
     <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
     <strong><?php echo $lang['hasError']; ?></strong> <?php echo $lang['login_error']; ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if (isset($error)) {
        echo $error;
    } ?>

      <div class="form-sign">
       <form method="post">
        <div class="form-head">
         <h3><?php echo $lang['register']; ?></h3>
        </div><!-- /.form-head -->

        <div class="form-body">

        <!-- List group -->
        <ul class="list-group">
         <li class="list-group-item">
          <div class="material-switch pull-center">
           <span class="pull-left"><?php echo $lang['freelancer'];      
 ?>     </span>
            <input id="someSwitchOptionDefault" name="user_type" type="checkbox"/>
            <label for="someSwitchOptionDefault" class="label-success">   </label>
           <span class="pull-right"><?php echo $lang['client']; ?></span>
          </div>
         </li>
        </ul> 

         <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-controls">
           <input type="text" name="name" class="field" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('name')); ?>"  placeholder="<?php echo $lang['full_name']; ?>">
          </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
         </div><!-- /.form-row -->          

         <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-controls">
           <input type="text" name="email" class="field" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('email')); ?>"  placeholder="<?php echo $lang['email']; ?>">
          </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
         </div><!-- /.form-row -->

         <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-controls">
           <input type="text" name="username" class="field" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('username')); ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['username']; ?>">
          </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
         </div><!-- /.form-row -->

         <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-controls">
           <input type="password" name="password" class="field" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['password']; ?>">
          </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
         </div><!-- /.form-row -->

         <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-controls">
           <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" class="field" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['confirm_password']; ?>">
          </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
         </div><!-- /.form-row -->

         </div><!-- /.form-body -->

         <div class="form-foot">
          <div class="form-actions">
           <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>" />
           <input value="<?php echo $lang['register']; ?>" class="form-btn" type="submit">
          </div><!-- /.form-actions -->
         </div><!-- /.form-foot -->
       </form>

      </div><!-- /.form-sign -->
     </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
    </main>

   </div><!-- /.row -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
 </section><!-- /section -->

 <!-- ==============================================
 Scripts
 =============================================== -->

 <!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
 <script src="assets/js/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 JS -->
 <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <!-- Typed JS -->
 <script src="assets/js/typed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <!-- Kafe JS -->
 <script src="assets/js/kafe.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: We can't help you without error log, probably your error_reporting is set to off in php.ini, you could set it to ON and you'll see what errors you get. Or your apache error log.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be issue with path of the file you are including;

```
require_once __DIR__.'core/core.php';
```

Comment: Why would that be? Shouldn't the code then fail in XAMP/localhost too?